# Adapt JSON code to use in VB.net - Parcel Perfect API

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

I am having difficulties adapting sample code which is in `json` format for use in a `vb.net` application. I have successfully adopted some of the code but I get various errors for all ideas when adapting a different part of the sample code.

The sample code I am working from is from the support team of the Parcel Perfect API.

I successfully interpreted
Supplied code:

```
$quoteParams = array();
$quoteParams['details'] = array();
$quoteParams['details']['waybill'] = "Y";
$quoteParams['details']['accnum'] = "1234";
```

To:

```
Dim QuoteA As Quote_requestQuote_Request = New Quote_requestQuote_Request
Dim dtls As New Quote_requestQuote_Request_Detail
dtls.waybill = "Y"
dtls.accnum = "1234"
QuoteA.details = dtls
```

The supplied sample code of my exact problem is:

```
//Create contents array object
    $quoteParams['contents'] = array();

    //Create first contents item (index 0 in the contents array)
    $quoteParams['contents'][0] = array();

    //Add contents details
    $quoteParams['contents'][0]['item'] = 1;
    $quoteParams['contents'][0]['desc'] = 'this is a test';
    $quoteParams['contents'][0]['dim1'] = 1;

    //Create second contents item (index 1 in the contents array)
    $quoteParams['contents'][1] = array();

    //Add contents details
    $quoteParams['contents'][1]['item'] = 2;
    $quoteParams['contents'][1]['desc'] = 'ths is another test';
    $quoteParams['contents'][1]['dim1'] = 1;
```

When running the code:

```
Dim contents As Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents = New Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents
    Dim ContArr(5) As Object
    ContArr(0) = 1
    ContArr(1) = "Testing"
    ContArr(2) = 30

    QuoteA.contents(0).item = ContArr(0)
    QuoteA.contents(0).description = ContArr(0)
    QuoteA.contents(0).dim1 = ContArr(0)
```

I need to loop through a set of records to add multiple items as contents of the `Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents`

I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when reaching `QuoteA.contents(0).item = ContArr(0)`.

I am open to suggestions as I am a relative newbie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents contains (I presume) multiple Quote_requestQuote_Request_Detail objects.  Typically, these would be initialized as follows:

```
Class Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents
.....
Sub New
Dim detail as new Quote_requestQuote_Request_Detail
.....
End Sub
```

Since that is apparently now the case, you need to do the work using something like this:

```
Dim contents As Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents = New Quote_requestQuote_Request_Contents
Dim detail as new Quote_requestQuote_Request_Detail
    <<Add information to detail>>
    contents.add(detail)
```

Now your contents object should not raise your error.  You can add as many detail objects to your contents object by repeating the process.

**Edit !:**
First, I suggest you change

```
Dim ContArr(5) As Object
```

to

```
Dim ContArr(5) As Array
```

Second, I suspect the error is in the way you are adding contents to QuoteA.  Try this:

```
QuoteA.contents.item(0) = ContArr(0)
QuoteA.contents.item(1) = ContArr(1)
QuoteA.contents.item(2) = ContArr(2)
```

....

This assumes Item(0) is the "item" property, Item(1) is the description, etc.

Comment: Thanks @SezMe, but the detail and contents are 2 different elements of the Quote_Request. The Detail is in essence the "Header" of the quote request, where we set a single line entry of various parameters. That part is correct.

The "Contents" are an Array which we will loop through to add multiple criteria (like Dimensions, weight, descrition etc) for multiple items on quote request. 
The array is to contain paramerter values like "$quoteParams['contents'][0]['item'] = 1;" "$quoteParams['contents'][0]['desc'] = 'this is a test'; 
It is the contents array I can't figure out.